# Email Google Form daily?

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to email out a Form created with Google daily? I would like to do this simply to email myself a form for use in personal data aggregation.

One specific use I'd like to do this for: I am an amateur musician, and I want to create a Form through which I can select the songs I've played (or if I've even played at all) daily. I could do this by going to Google Drive, selecting the form, and filling it out daily, but the email feature would be a convenient and handy reminder, especially since I can easily fill it out while in Gmail.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "embed" the form in an email, and then use "boomerang" to send that email repeatedly... Here's a excerpt from two pages:

[How to Embed A Survey Form in Email And Receive Higher Completion Rate [Google Forms]](http://www.maketecheasier.com/embed-google-forms-in-email/)

> Creating & Embedding a Google Form in Email
>
> 1. From your Gmail account, navigate to Google Drive and click “Create -> Form”.
> 2. Complete the necessary questions for your survey (as shown below) and click Done.
> 3. When the “send the form to others” dialog box pops up, enter in the relevant email address you want to send the form to and ensure the
>    “Include form in this email is ticked”. When you’re sure all the
>    details are correct, click “Send”.
> 4. When the client receives the email, they will see the survey embedded in the email and will be allowed to answer it directly
>    instead of using the link. As shown in the example below, the
>    recipient chooses the appropriate radio buttons and clicks Submit.
> 5. When the Submit button is clicked, a message box pops up stating that the recipient is submitting the information to an external
>    website. They will need to click OK to continue.
> 6. A new tab opens (within the relevant browser) indicating the survey has been submitted.
> 7. To ensure that the response was successfully received, navigate to the form in Google Drive and open up the survey form. The results
>    should be recorded as shown below.
>
> As previously stated, Google forms cannot be filled out within an
> email unless the recipient is using Gmail or Google Apps. This means
> that if the form is sent to emails such as Outlook or Yahoo, there is
> no option available to submit the survey directly within the email.
> Instead, the user has to click on the external link to access the
> survey page.

**I'd suggest you use the above info, and email the form to yourself. Then use the info below to send it repeatedly**

[How to send recurring emails and reminders](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/l/how-to-send-recurring-emails.html)

> Our demo video above shows you how to send recurring emails right from
> your inbox. Whether you need to remind employees about biweekly
> events, make sure your roommates pay the utility bills every month, or
> remind yourself to stick with a new habit every morning, Boomerang’s
> recurring messages feature will make short work of it. To set up a
> recurring email, all you have to do is write a message like normal,
> click ‘Schedule Recurring Message’ from the bottom of the Send Later
> menu.
>
> From the pop-up menu, you can then choose the start date, frequency,
> day of the week to send, and end date. You can easily change, edit, or
> cancel a scheduled message from the manage page. It’s that easy!
>
> *With the Boomerang for Gmail extension, you can schedule easy recurring email reminders right from your inbox.*

Links are already provided in the title of each quoted text above...

Comment: This looks great. Thanks for the help. It's an old question, but I'm glad to finally have a succinct answer to the question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done without the need of 3rd party apps by using Google App Scripts.

Just to give you an idea the procedure would be:

1. Create a Form in Google Forms and email it to yourself
2. Get the HTML from that email and copy it to your clipboard
3. Create a new Google App script with the following code:

   `function sendFormEmail() {
       var emailAddress = "Some email address";
       var htmlMessage = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Name of your HTML file").getContent();
       var subject = "Subject";
       var message = "Some message";
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
           htmlBody: htmlMessage
       });
   }`
4. Create a new HTML and paste the email content (make sure the name of the file matches the string in the code)
5. Choose the frequency in which you (or whoever you want) would like to receive the email.

You can see the full step by step tutorial here: http://jivimberg.github.io/blog/2014/08/21/email-google-form-daily/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using IFTTT and scheduling a daily (or hourly in my case) email containing the link to the survey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script for this or create a repeating event in Google Calendar:
[Create a repeating event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37115?hl=en)

Comment: How would one do that in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Its been a year since i have done anything in app script. But i believe that you can use time driven triggers + gmail services in app script to script to send regular emails